# How to combine buy binds with key bindings?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Unified buy binds, for example binding <kbd>D</kbd> to buy defuser and <kbd>S</kbd> to buy smoke improve the flow of game as I don't have to open the buy menu in the first place. Unfortunately creating a bind unbinds the respective key bind.

I have tried creating an alias, but this results in the same outcome:

```
alias "+movesmoke" "+back; buy smokegrenade"
alias -movesmoke -back
bind s +movesmoke
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend using the main movement keys to buy something. You might cause the spam filter to trigger (too many commands in a short amount of time), which will block further commands for some time.

What you're asking for is:
`bind S "+back; buy smokegrenade"`

...but a better solution is using unused keys, like the numpad or some F-keys. You can even buy a complete loadout within seconds. That's how I do it.

For example:

```
bind KP_INS "buy vesthelm;buy vest"
bind KP_DEL "buy defuser"
bind KP_ENTER "buy smokegrenade"
bind KP_PLUS "buy hegrenade;buy incgrenade;buy molotov"
bind KP_MINUS "buy flashbang"
```

This will let you buy your equipment without any problems. <kbd>0</kbd> buys armor, <kbd>,</kbd> buys a defuser and the right sided keys all grenades. You can extend this by using the numbers to buy specific weapons or even a donation button: `bind KP_5 "buy m4a1;buy ak47;drop"` (this buys a rifle and drops it right away).^

**Edit:**

Combining a "*+something*" command with other stuff seems to cause unexpected behavior. You can avoid this by using an alias. I have successfully tested this one:

```
alias +mvgren "+back; buy smokegrenade"
alias -mvgren "-back"
bind s "+mvgren"
```

(you can name that alias whatever you want)

Comment: `bind S +back; buy smokegrenade` doesn't appear to work, my own grenade bind `bind enter "buy smokegrenade; buy flashbang"` does. Grenade is only purchased when I enter the command.

Comment: Have you used this command recently? Do I have to unbind the `S` key first perhaps?

Comment: @user198327 try encasing in "", `bind s "command; command"`. Can't test it here, but the syntax should work, since I use similar settings. It could as well be that the game blocks additional binds on movement keys.

Comment: There's something odd going on - I entered `bind S "+back; buy smokegrenade"` to console and the game purchases a HE grenade when I press `S`.

Comment: I understand that Arqade isn't a script troubleshooting service, sorry in advance if my personal configuration causes this issue. I didn't dismiss your recommendation off-hand and I use the numpad keys for buy binds, but I hit a wrong key too often, throwing of in-game economical balance.

Comment: @user198327 yep.. new buy binds need some getting used to. Do other keys work and buy the correct items and only the s key causes this issue?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I have around 10 buy binds, including alphabetical keys. I tested and `bind S "+back; buy hegrenade"` purchases HE grenade, `bind S "+back; buy flashgrenade"` and `bind S "+back; buy decoy"` also buys the grenade. It seems that every command including `bind S "+back; buy ak47` buys HE grenade instead!

Comment: @user198327 I'll check it out as soon as I can. That's really strange behavior

Comment: @user198327 I found the problem and edited my answer.

Comment: **Your script is identical to [mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/319880/198327)** (I think quotes are only necessary with commands containing spaces) **!** I must have made a mistake, I briefly tested the script around two years ago and commented it out in my autoexec as "non-functional".

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much the same, but the quotes did the trick.

Comment: I mean that my script does work after all, I pasted it to console before even trying yours. I still reward you for research.

Comment: @user198327 even without quotes? good to know. they seem to be buggy sometimes..

Comment: Not entirely without quotes, I copied the script from my original question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/319880/198327

Comment: Do you want to add [this information](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/320405/198327) to your answer? Please correct if I'm wrong about alias, but the commands certainly work.

Comment: @user198327 although they should work they didn't for me for some reason and I'm not sure why. Binding something directly to a "+ bind" created an unwanted loop in my case. Anyway, it's already in my answer in the first paragraph :)

Answer (score 1):

In `Counter-Strike 1.6` and before you could bind multiple actions to a button by using `;` separator, I'm pretty sure this is the same for `CS:GO`. For example, this bind will make you kill with 1 shot, even if you shoot in the air(even with a flashbang):

```
bind mouse1 "+attack;kill"
```

Comment: "kill with one shot"? Do you mean "attack with one click", when you don't have  a gun equipped?

Comment: @user198327 `kill` just kills yourself. If you bind it to a key you have a suicide button.

Comment: @dly yes, that's it. So you will basically shoot and 1 shot will be enough for a kill :D

Answer (score 1):

Using alias isn't necessary. Unless you want to give your commands a name, alias only adds complexity and length ([source](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=314801693)).

Binds for your examples:

```
bind s "+back;buy smokegrenade;"
```

```
bind d "+moveright;buy defuser;"
```