# What is the command for strafing?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm [combining buy binds with key bindings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319880/how-to-combine-buy-binds-with-key-bindings), but I'm unable to use  "left" and "right" movement keys as I don't know the strafe command. `+right` and `+left` commands turn the camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For strafing you can use the default command:

```
+moveleft
+moveright
```