# How to switch weapons and items using a command?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Obviously you should use keys instead of console to switch weapons and items, but [combining buy bindings with key binds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319880/how-to-combine-buy-binds-with-key-bindings) can streamline the buying phase. Using [flashbang](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Flashbang) as an example, neither `+weapon_flashbang` nor `+flashbang` works for switching (the command purchases the item, but the key isn't bound):

```
bind f "weapon_flashbang;buy flashbang;"
```

```
bind f "flashbang;buy flashbang;"
```

Comment: Do you want to actually *use* them or just switch to them to hold them in your hand?

Comment: @dly: Only *switch*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings to switch to a specific weapon slot are...

- `slot1` primary
- `slot2` pistols
- `slot3` knife
- `slot4` grenades

or for a specific item you can use the command `use <item name>`, such as `use weapon_hegrenade` or `use weapon_flashbang`

These can all be used in binds or buy scripts:

`bind <key> "buy ak47; slot1"`
`bind <key> "buy deagle; slot2"`

or to switch to a specific item:
`bind <key> "buy hegrenade; use weapon_hegrenade"`